# How do I create a method that compares 2 integer arrays and get a percentage of how alike they are?

Tags: java, algorithm, comparison

For a personal project I need to make a method, that compares two integer arrays and outputs how a percentage value of how alike they are. The arrays can be of different lengths from each other.

I.E. these could be examples of arrays I can get:

```
    int[] array1 = {21, 154, 25, 180, 2, 159, 25, 25, 181, 25, 3, 181, 25, 180, 2, 160, 4, 179, 21, 2, 159, 17, 54, 21, 158, 25, 180, 21, 25, 180, 21, 4, 100, 46, 79, 25, 180, 21, 25, 180, 21, 4};
    int[] array2 = {21, 154, 25, 180, 2, 159, 25, 25, 181, 25, 3, 181, 25, 180, 2, 160, 4, 179, 17, 54, 167, 25, 180, 21, 25, 180, 21, 4, 100, 46, 79, 25, 180, 21, 25, 180, 21, 4, 100, 50, 83, 25, 180, 21, 25, 180};
```

As you can see the first part is the same but the last part only has some comparison.

Comment: You must define likeness criteria

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: no a friend asked me for help

Comment: You should be a bit more clear in your question. I guess you don't have an idea how to apply a score to the difference between two arrays? In either way, the scoring-function will be quite dependant upon the constraints on the input-arrays.

Comment: and.. what have you tried? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

**I assume that you have to count number of common elements, and then do something about it.**

Your problem is strictly algorithmic one: the easiest solution is sort arrays (n*log(n)) then iterate through them in order get how many elements they have in common (it's possible to do it in one loop so you have n operations). It gives us O(n*log(n) + n) what is (n*log(n)).

But there is better approach - you can use associative arrays, your need then more memory (for this additional arrays), then check how many they have in common. It gives you n for putting in arrays and n for finding how many they have in common. So you have O(n+n) so it's O(n).

```
public class Compare {

public static Integer min(Integer a, Integer b) {
    if (a != null && b != null) {
        if (a.intValue() > b.intValue())
            return b;
        else
            return a;
    } else
        // If any of them is null
        return 0;

}

public static void how_many_common(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {

    System.out.println("First arr has " + arr1.length);
    System.out.println("Second arr has " + arr2.length);
    Map<Integer, Integer> arr1_map = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Integer> arr2_map = new HashMap<>();
    // Put first arr in Hash map
    for (int i : arr1) {
        Integer how_many = arr1_map.get(i);
        if (how_many != null) {
            arr1_map.put(i, how_many + 1);
        } else {
            arr1_map.put(i, 1);
        }
    }
    // Put second arr in Hash map
    for (int i : arr2) {
        Integer how_many = arr2_map.get(i);
        if (how_many != null) {
            arr2_map.put(i, how_many + 1);
        } else {
            arr2_map.put(i, 1);
        }
    }
    int sumOfCommon = 0;
    for (int i : arr1_map.keySet()) {
        sumOfCommon += min(arr1_map.get(i), arr2_map.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println("Arrays have " + sumOfCommon + " numbers in common");
    //Rest of likeliness is for you

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array1 = {21, 154, 25, 180, 2, 159, 25, 25, 181, 25, 3, 181, 25, 180, 2, 160, 4, 179, 21, 2, 159, 17, 54, 21, 158, 25, 180, 21, 25, 180, 21, 4, 100, 46, 79, 25, 180, 21, 25, 180, 21, 4};
    int[] array2 = {21, 154, 25, 180, 2, 159, 25, 25, 181, 25, 3, 181, 25, 180, 2, 160, 4, 179, 17, 54, 167, 25, 180, 21, 25, 180, 21, 4, 100, 46, 79, 25, 180, 21, 25, 180, 21, 4, 100, 50, 83, 25, 180, 21, 25, 180};
    how_many_common(array1, array2);
    int [] array3 = {1,2,3,4};
    int [] array4 = {1,2,3,4};
    how_many_common(array3, array4);
    int [] array5 = {};
    int [] array6 = {1,2,3,4};
    how_many_common(array5, array6);
    int [] array7 = {5};
    int [] array8 = {1,2,3,4};
    how_many_common(array7, array8);
}
}
```

It's completed working solution of second approach.